# toad for oracle alter table ddl export

Tags: oracle, export, ddl, toad, alter

I use Toad for Oracle v12.6 and able to see DDL export for full table under the Database menu. 
Does anyone know is it possible to generate DDL for spesific columns of a table?

With an example; I have table **Employees** with 5 columns like:

```
EmpID    INTEGER,
Name     VARCHAR2(100),
SurName  VARCHAR2(100),
Age      INTEGER,
Address  VARCHAR2(200)
```

I want to generate alter script for **Age** and **Address** columns only using Toad for Oracle.

**Edit:** I do not want to alter the table, I want to have an "alter table add column Age and Address with datatypes" script as below;

```
ALTER TABLE Employees ADD Age Integer;
ALTER TABLE Employees ADD Address VARCHAR2(200);
```

Any help would be appropriated.

Answer (score 0):

### yes you can do it just with  toad

first you should click alter table:

[image]

then you can  modify

[image]

Comment: And where is the generated alter script ?